# MySQL query join, select on two columns, not equal on another column

Tags: mysql

My working query is below. However, the results from that query will produce duplicates AND non duplicates on name column. I want to be able to only show results where name columns from the two select queries are different

```
select t.*
from tbl_user_tmp t JOIN
(select activity, class, count(*) as NumDuplicates
from tbl_user_tmp
where user = 'bignadad2'
group by activity, class
having NumDuplicates > 1)
tsum ON t.activity = tsum.activity and t.class = tsum.class
```

**columns are in this order**

id, name, activity, class, activity_id

I only want to show these results where activity, class match and name does not.

```
2059    lg_lmk          com.lge.lmk    com.lge.lmk.activities.LmkMainActivity   48255
3668    task_manager    com.lge.lmk    com.lge.lmk.activities.LmkMainActivity   48255
```

These are the other results i do not want to see

```
2690    phone   com.modoohut.dialer    com.modoohut.dialer.DialActivity    54700
2694    phone   com.modoohut.dialer    com.modoohut.dialer.DialActivity    54700
```

Comment: We can't tell from your question which column is which.

Comment: Try to join by `id`, not `activity` and `class`. **UPD**: I'm not quite understand - why you use JOIN? May be sub-select is the query you needed?

Comment: okay. would you mind suggesting something that is better?

Comment: i made the column order in the question bold so you can see it

Comment: What is you needed? Is my [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c8d84/2) shows all you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that you needs only some results

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user_tmp AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT activity, class, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM tbl_user_tmp
    WHERE user = 'first'
    GROUP BY activity, class
    HAVING cnt > 1
) AS t2
ON t1.activity = t2.activity AND t1.class = t2.class

WHERE user = 'first' -- remove records of the other users
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.activity, t1.class -- select distinct records
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c01d2/1)

If `class` is unique in the `activity` then you can remove `activity` from the `GROUP BY`-statement.

Comment: It mostly works. check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09765/2/0 its still showing result where name, activity and class match

Comment: Stop... Are you want exclude results that occur more than once? Ok, `HAVING COUNT(1) = 1` helps you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09765/5

Comment: okay. this works great! one more question. Im using this for a jqgrid table and i need a query that counts the total results your query produces. Ive tried many things and cannot get it.

Comment: I don't know about jqgrid but you can get total count by `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in the your limited query and then run `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` query: [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

I don't know why but SQLFiddle returns [wrong result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09765/9) (count = 0) but my local client returns right value (count = 2)